# Sorting a SortedDictionary of <String,int> Alphabetically, reverse Alphabetically, and the value's frequency

Tags: c#, dictionary, alphabetical, sorteddictionary

I'm brand new to C# and the concept of hash tables/dictionary's and have been searching for a straight answer on this for quite awhile, but I can not find any solutions that actually works (likely due to my ignorance of the subject) so I need a solution in simple terms if possible.

Also, if it makes a difference, the `String`s and `int`s in the dictionary are not data members or even parameters.

More Description:

The program overall, is to import words via text file or direct user input then save them and the number of times they appear (AKA store in `Dictionary/Sorteddictionary`) then allow users to reorganize the data, alphabetically, reverse alphabetically, or by frequency and/OR print them to the console or write the data to a new .txt file.

However right now I am only trying to get the sorting of the dictionary to work.

Example input:
Another great story and another great adventure.

Example Output(alphabetically):
Words Starting with letter A:
another adventure and
Letter Starting with letter G:
great
(Ect.)

Example Output(reverse alphabetically):
Words Starting with letter S:
story
Words Starting with letter G:
great
(ect.)

Output(frequency):
number of words occurring 2 time(s):
another great
number of words occurring 1 time(s):
and adventure story.

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to do or what doesn't work. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: added more description. As for code Im sure Im at a point where i basically need to start from scratch.

Comment: Examples of input, desired output etc would be helpful

Comment: SortedDictionary isn't actually implemented as a hash table, it's implemented as a tree based data structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps.  I'm not sure it's the best way to approach your problem, but it should help you to familiarise yourself with some of the options / see why some of the guys on here are advising against it.  If you let us know more about what you're trying to do we can better advise alternate approaches.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace StackOverflow.Demos
{
    class Program
    {

        const string OutputFormat = "{0}: {1}";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program();
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public Program()
        {
            SortedDictionary<string, int> dic = new SortedDictionary<string, int>();
            dic.Add("a", 1);
            dic.Add("b", 2);
            dic.Add("d", 2);
            dic.Add("c", 1);
            dic.Add("e", 1);
            dic.Add("f", 3);
            dic.Add("g", 4);
            dic.Add("h", 2);
            dic.Add("i", 2);

            OutputByKeyAsc(dic);
            OutputByKeyDesc(dic);
            OutputByValueFrequency(dic);
        }

        void OutputByKeyAsc(SortedDictionary<string, int> dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OutputByKeyAsc");
            foreach (string key in dic.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, key, dic[key]));
            }
        }

        void OutputByKeyDesc(SortedDictionary<string, int> dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OutputByKeyDesc");
            foreach (string key in dic.Keys.Reverse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, key, dic[key]));
            }
        }

        void OutputByValueFrequency(SortedDictionary<string, int> dic)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OutputByValueFrequency");

            IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<int,int>> values = 
                (
                    from sortedItem 
                    in 
                    (
                        from entry 
                        in dic 
                        group entry 
                        by entry.Value
                        into result
                        select new KeyValuePair<int,int>(result.Key , result.Count())
                    )
                    orderby sortedItem.Value descending
                    select sortedItem
                ).ToArray();

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, int> value in values)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> item in dic.Where<KeyValuePair<string, int>>(item => item.Value == value.Key))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, item.Key, string.Format(OutputFormat, item.Value, value.Value)));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Good luck / hope you're enjoying c# so far.

**EDIT**

Based on the new info in your question here's my attempt at a neater solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace StackOverflow.Demos
{
    class Program
    {

        const string OutputFormat = "{0}: {1}";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program("Another great story and another great adventure.");
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public Program(string userInput)
        {
            //break string into words
            IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, int>> words = Regex.Split(userInput, @"\W+").GroupBy(word => word.ToLowerInvariant(), word => 1); //nb converting word to lower case to avoid case sensitive comparisons in grouping - I can keep the original value(s) by replacing "word => 1" with "word => word" if needed

            Console.WriteLine("\nWords in alphabetic order");
            foreach (IGrouping<string, int> wordInfo in words.OrderBy(word => word.Key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, wordInfo.Key,wordInfo.Count()));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nWords in descending alphabetic order");
            foreach (IGrouping<string, int> wordInfo in words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Key))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Count()));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nWords by frequency (desc)");
            foreach (IGrouping<string, int> wordInfo in words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Count()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Count()));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's the same code with the functionality in a class and the output kept in the program:
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
namespace StackOverflow.Demos
{
    class Program
    {

        const string OutputFormat = "{0}: {1}";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program("Another great story and another great adventure.");
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public Program(string userInput)
        {
            WordCounter myWordCounter = new WordCounter(userInput);
            Console.WriteLine("\n**Alphabetical**");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> wordInfo in myWordCounter.GetWordCountByWordAlphabeticalDesc())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat,wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Value));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n**Alphabetical Desc**");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> wordInfo in myWordCounter.GetWordCountByWordAlphabeticalDesc())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Value));
            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n**Frequency Desc**");
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> wordInfo in myWordCounter.GetWordCountByFrequency())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format(OutputFormat, wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Value));
            }
        }

    }

    public class WordCounter
    {
        string sentance;
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, int>> words;
        public WordCounter(string sentance)
        {
            this.sentance = sentance;
            GetWords();
        }
        void GetWords()
        {
            this.words = Regex.Split(this.sentance, @"\W+").GroupBy(word => word.ToLowerInvariant(), word => 1);
        }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetWordCountByWordAlphabetical()
        {
            return this.words.OrderBy(word => word.Key).Select(wordInfo => new KeyValuePair<string,int>(wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Count()));
        }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetWordCountByWordAlphabeticalDesc()
        {
            return this.words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Key).Select(wordInfo => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Count()));
        }
        public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, int>> GetWordCountByFrequency()
        {
            return this.words.OrderByDescending(word => word.Count()).Select(wordInfo => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(wordInfo.Key, wordInfo.Count()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you helpful posts however I need the code you've posted in a separate TUI class. When in inserted and fix to project specs the for loop yields this error "foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type void because void does not contain a public definition for 'GETenumerator'" Can you explain the meaning of this error and give me some advice on how to fix it?

Comment: No worries - I've put the code into the same layer as the UI for demo purposes.  To get it to work as a library create functions which return IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,int>> results then return the results of the OrderBys (or replace console.writeline with yield return statements for a simpler solution).

Comment: I,m sorry, can you explain that in a simpler way please or show me an example?

Comment: No worries, I've refactored the code into a separate class - just use the WordCount class - the stuff before it (in Program) shows you how to use that class.

Comment: Again thank you for all your help. I haven't been able to test the last post yet but if run into any more problems i will post back here.

Answer (score 0):

Since you aren't *always* displaying the data in a single consistently sorted manor I don't see any compelling reason to store the data in a sorted manor.  You're likely better off just storing the data however you want, and then sorting it whenever the user requests to see it in some particularly sorted manor.

Comment: Im unsure on how to do that either.

Comment: LINQ's OrderBy method is an effective means of taking any data structure and returning all of the values sorted in some particular manor.

Comment: I've tried that. however every example on how to use the OrderBy method has only led to more confutation because I can never seem to understand what the parameters are and what they are doing. Also most examples I've seen reference a saved variable or data member which i do not have.